# the probability of answering randomly at least 6 times correctly.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, analysis

> a MCQ exam has 10 questions, for each question 4 answers are proposed,
> only one is correct. give the probability of answering randomly at
> least 6 times correctly .

i know the right  answer :we need to calculate  the probability of getting exactly 6 questions answered right + the probability of getting exactly 7 questions answered right +..

but i tried to calculate it in other way:let's choose 6 question  to be answered  right so we have ${10 \choose 6}$ ,each of those 6 questions  have only one answer which is the right answer,now it still 4 questions each of them can be answered  right or wrong,so each of them can accept 4 answers

so the probability of answering randomly at least 6 times correctly is $\frac{{10 \choose 6}4⁴}{4^{10}}$

**-is this  way  also right?**

Comment: Did you try comparing the two calculations? Say in mathway, or Wolfram alpha, and see whether they give the same answer?

Comment: The method suggested here will overestimate the probability.

Comment: i did the calculations quickly ,i found them different.so now i  ask  why the second method is not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason here is overlapping of selected events. Let us consider a smaller sample space. 4 questions with at least 3 correct. With the first method the cases formed are:

```
Correct Wrong
ABC     D
ABD     C
ACD     B
BCD     A
ABCD    None
```

So, we get 5 such cases.
With the second method the case of all questions being right is repeated every time.

```
If ABC are correct, we count 2 cases D right and D wrong
If ABD are correct, we count 2 cases C right and C wrong
```

Here all right case was counted twice. Similarly even more cases will be repeated in a larger sample space resulting in an overestimated probability.